# In a universe with loop dimensions how is the density of a massive body calculated?

Tags: space, spacetime-dimensions, dimensions

In ordinary 3D space one can calculate the density (average density) of a massive body by dividing the mass of that body by the volume it inhabits
D = M/V with M in say kg and V in say m^3 so D = [kg/m^3]. If there were one small loop dimension "attached" to each definable point in 3D space, how would that affect the volume & hence density calculation? The net result should be D = [kg/m^4] I imagine, but how would the exact value be calculated?

Comment: There's loads of stuff speculated about loop dimensions in this universe, we manage. How are you defining density if not relative to mass and volume?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you call the "volume" in this scenario. I am also not sure that I understand how the proposed space works. Could you please provide the relevant definitions? It would also be very useful to provide an actual meaning for the word "small".

Comment: If the dimensions are subatomic, then it's a normal extension of the existing mass. Otherwise, you have to decide how "thick" things are in that other dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You're just calculating density in 4-space. The fact that one of the dimensions happens to be small, and that it happens to be looped, is completely irrelevant. (It's relevant to *other* bits of physics, but just for calculating density, completely immaterial.)

The "volume" (or bulk) of a 4D space is just the volume of a 3D cross-section multiplied by its extent in the fourth direction--or, more generally, the integral of 3D volumes across the fourth direction. This is *exactly* analogous to how 2D area is the integral of 1D lengths across the second direction, and how 3D volume is the integral of 2D areas across the third direction. The only difference is that you are putting a maximum limit on the bounds of integration--the total length of the looped dimension.

Since you only have *one* looped dimension, then it induces a preferred orientation and scale in 4-space, and objects significantly larger than the inherent scale can be approximated as effectively 3-dimensional, with constant (maximum) extent in the 4th dimension. In which case, you can measure the 3-density in the normal manner.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the properties of the loop dimension.

It is different from other dimensions anyway because it is a loop, so the laws that apply to regular dimensions that stretch out in a linear manner do not necessarily apply at all. So, it is all speculation & imagination.

Therefore: what are you aiming at? What purpose does this serve in your world.

Comment: Well, if such a universe could be modeled by a computer, the physics would need to be defined & it was just a small starting point I thought of.

Comment: @DarrenNicholls Ok, I see. Defining physics in this manner is a bit too open a question, because as of now loop dimensions are purely speculative, and no one can give you a definite answer how they would work. As the worldbuilder, it is up to you to come up with the big picture, while others can only help you with aspects such as details or internal consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the Science here is speculation in various string theories and the [M-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory).

---

Suppose you have 1 kg of a monoatomic gas in 1 m³ of a box. In the normal 3 dimensional space (ignoring the time dimension), the density would be 1 kg/m³. Now imagine there are some hyper-dimensional loops in that box which are from a spatial dimension > 3. These hyper-dimensions have the property that anything smaller than their own size can be teleported from one loop to another distant loop as they form quantum tunnels in higher dimensions (distance measured is still in three usual space dimensions). For the sake of our example, let's suppose that these loops are large enough to let at least one gaseous atom pass through it at one time.

When you observe the state of the atoms in the box, it is likely that you will find the density very slightly *lower* than 1kg/m³ due to some atoms residing within the tunnels formed by those loops so that they might evade the three normal space dimensions and hence the observation.

Also note that since these hyper-dimensions allow such a teleportation unlike the usual 3-D space, they might not necessarily have an integer exponent in their unit in density or volume. For example, they most likely could have volume like $\ce{m^{\frac{11}{3}}}$ or density of matter as 1kg/$\ce{m^{\frac{11}{3}}}$ or anything of the sort.